# Nullpointer when using @Autowire

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to create a [DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) object by [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (@Autowire) but unfortunately, this DAO object is never created and hence a Nullpointer exception is thrown.

This is my DAO implementation:

```
package com.sample.dao.service;

@Component
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Autowired
    OrderServiceImpl(OrderRepository orderRepository) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Order order) {
        return orderRepository.save(order);
    }
```

The class where the Nullpointer exception is caused:

```
package com.sample.dispatcher;

@Component
public class OrderDispatcher  {

    private final OrderServiceImpl orderServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    public OrderDispatcher(OrderServiceImpl orderServiceImpl) {
        this.orderServiceImpl = orderServiceImpl;
    }

    public void createOrder(Order order) {
        orderServiceImpl.save(order));   //  --> Nullpointer
```

My entry class:

```
package com.sample;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sample" , "com.webservice"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.sample.dao.repository")
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

Comment: OrderDispatcher is dependent to OrderServiceImpl and OrderServiceImpl in dependent to OrderRepository. Check if OrderRepository is initialized properly.

Comment: Is there any error on Spring boot startup?

Comment: Have you annotated OrderRepository  ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your constructor to have an argument type of *interface* rather than a *concrete implementation*. So something like this -

```
@Component
public class OrderDispatcher  {

private final OrderService orderServiceImpl;

@Autowired
public OrderDispatcher(OrderService orderServiceImpl) {
        this.orderServiceImpl = orderServiceImpl;
        }
```

When you add the `@component` notation on OrderServiceImpl, [Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot) creates proxy for that class and it can be autowired by interface.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot the `@annotation` *configuration*. Try adding this class and also you scan your entities: EntityScan

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@Configuration
@EntityScan("com.sample.model") // Your model package
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sample" , "com.webservice"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.sample.dao.repository")
public class RepositoryConfig {

}
```